# Some way to change text of SWF without having Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a FLA with some text but the person that will be sending the SWF doesn't have Flash and doesn't know anything about Flash either.

Is there some way to build the FLA so that the text can be changed simply by modifying the SWF somehow? Due to company policy, the SWF cannot read from external files.

We tried programming into the FLA that it read an XML in another server, but that's not allowed. I also cannot send the SWF with another file (ie. an xml file).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a strange logic to try to modify a FLA file without Flash. A FLA file is a binary file, you'll need an editor to read it and I'm pretty sure Adobe isn't allowing 3rd party editors legally.

But yes, it's fine to have a dynamic TextField where you can send the parameter and change the data. Please note - you need to send the data. Means it has to come from outside.

What are the options? Well, actually, there are few:

- Loading from an external file or getting it from a server side script. You said it's not allowed, let's omit this method.
- Read FlashVars. If you publish it within a HTML page, you can actually feed some data via FlashVars. Not only 1 variable, but as many as you want. And it's fine for small strings, but if you plan to pass a text larger than a sentence… Don't do it.
- As a funny hack you could try naming your file with the text you want and read the URL of the SWF thus showing it's name and using it as a text data. But don't do it :)
  **^**
  If you want to try it, you can access the URL with `stage.loaderInfo.url`, just make sure you have a stage defined - call in the document class or after the display object you're calling from is added to stage.
- Use ExternalInterface to communicate with, for example, JavaScript and get the variables from JavaScript. It's actually not so bad, since your text will be tidily stored in a .js file and you can modify it on the run. That of course is a separate file and you need to have the SWF embedded in HTML for that, but it is one of the options you have.

Other than that you could have an external file that will hold the data and embed it in the SWF. Look more on embedding here: http://flashgamedojo.com/wiki/index.php?title=Embedding_XML_in_AS3 . It is about embedding XML data, but you can use the technique for any data, even binary.
Embedding data is a great thing, but you'll need to re-compile each time you make a change in the file, since it isn't loading the file dynamically, but embeds it into to the SWF itself on compile time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: No problem! Please mark the post as "answered" if I answered your question, so other people could find an answer to a similar problem

Comment: I added something else to that comment, but apparently it didn't load correctly.
I was talking to the web admin for the newspaper site and they tell me that they use Google DFP (DoubleClick for Publishers). Is it possible that Google DFP doesn't allow a SWF to connect to an XML file in another server?

Answer (score 2):

Use [FLASM](http://www.nowrap.de/flasm.html) or [SWFMILL](http://swfmill.org/) which are free command line assembler/disassembler for swf files. Use any of the one to disassemble your swf. You can open the result file in any of the text editor, ***find and replace your text*** and assemble it as swf again. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[JPEXS Decompiler](https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler) can change text in an SWF pretty easily. It's still actively developed as of 2021.